# Emacs and cygwin

Tags: windows, shell, emacs, cygwin, cmd

How can I change my GNUemacs to open up a cygwin terminal rather then a cmd one with the shell command?

> **Closed** as duplicate of  [How can I run Cygwin Bash Shell from within Emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235254/how-can-i-run-cygwin-bash-shell-from-within-emacs).

Comment: See question [How can I run Cygwin Bash Shell from within Emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235254/how-can-i-run-cygwin-bash-shell-from-within-emacs).