# problem with unix date util running in emacs shell

Tags: bash, shell, emacs

here's a oddity.

on Cygwin bash on Windows Vista, i can get date like this:

```
$ date
2010-11-30  4:40:48 AM PST

xah@xah-PC ~
$ date +%s
1291120855
```

but in emacs “shell”, running the same date command, i get this:

```
c:\Users\xah\web\xahlee_org\comp>which date
which date
/usr/bin/date

c:\Users\xah\web\xahlee_org\comp>date
date
The current date is: 2010-11-30 
Enter the new date: (yy-mm-dd) 


c:\Users\xah\web\xahlee_org\comp>date +%s
date +%s
The system cannot accept the date entered.
Enter the new date: (yy-mm-dd)
```

any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because your emacs shell is actually a Windows Command Prompt shell and the date command gets sent to it and fails.

Take a look at this question to find out how you can configure emacs to use Cygwin's bash shell instead:

[How can I run Cygwin Bash Shell from within Emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235254/how-can-i-run-cygwin-bash-shell-from-within-emacs)

Answer (score 2):

You're hitting cmd.exe's date builtin, which is in no way like POSIX date(1). You could work around this by typing in the full path to the date command that you want.