# Garbage characters in my Windows Emacs shell. . . not sure what's wrong

Tags: bash, shell, emacs, windows-shell

I'm running GNU Emacs (23.1.1) on Windows and when I run a cygwin shell inside emacs I get garbage like the following, after each command:

```
^[]0;/cygdrive/c/emacs-23.1/bin
^[[32user@HOST [33m/cygdrive/c/emacs-23.1/bin[0m
```

Note: I've replaced my real user and host name with user/HOST.

I've found a few links that describe how to set up emacs with cygwin on Windows including this one on SO:
[How can I run Cygwin Bash Shell from within Emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235254/how-can-i-run-cygwin-bash-shell-from-within-emacs)

That hasn't helped.  As of right now, I don't have anything referencing shells in my .emacs file except for this:

```
;; For the interactive shell
(setq explicit-shell-file-name "bash")
```

So I'm not even sure how emacs is finding my cygwin shell.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Your TERM environment variable is set incorrectly; those are escape sequences for generating color output which aren't supported in the emacs shell.

Comment: Any idea how to do change it via my .emacs file?

Answer (score 3):

Try adding these lines to your .emacs file

```
(autoload 'ansi-color-for-comint-mode-on "ansi-color" nil t)
(add-hook 'shell-mode-hook 'ansi-color-for-comint-mode-on)
```

I'm not sure if these are the correct ones but let me know (as my .emacs file has gotten quite large over the years)

Comment: That just changed the color of the fonts.  But thanks.  I know it's something stupid that I forgot to set.  I don't really know too much about elisp.

Comment: Yeah it's supposed to, that's what those weird symbols are doing is setting ANSI colors.

Comment: this fixed my problem on Windows 10