# I want to run the cygwin bash shell from native windows emacs app

Tags: emacs, cygwin

I have followed instructions from [How can I run Cygwin Bash Shell from within Emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235254/how-can-i-run-cygwin-bash-shell-from-within-emacs) this question and I have gone further and added the `(setq explicit-bash-args '("--login" "-i"))` command, however emacs continues to only display the dos prompt when I type `M-x shell`. In summery my .emacs file looks like this:

```
(defun cygwin-shell ()
  "Run cygwin bash in shell mode."
  (interactive)
  (let ((explicit-shell-file-name "C:/cygwin/bin/bash"))
    (call-interactively 'shell)))
(setq explicit-bash-args '("--login" "-i"))`
```

Please be gentle with the answers as I am right at the bottom of the famous vertical emacs learning curve!

Comment: as patrick said, you should start shell by `M-x cygwin-shell`

Comment: Note also that you have emacs shell at `M-x eshell` which is kind of like bash, without cygwin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you implemented the *answer* from that question, note that you have to do `M-x cygwin-shell` to start bash. If you want to use it for every `M-x shell` you need to call

```
(setq explicit-shell-file-name "C:/cygwin/bin/bash")
```

---

Since you stated that you are learning, here's a few tips when trying this out.

- type `C-x C-f ~/.emacs` to open your .emacs file in your user path.
- Enter your function above at the end
- `M-x load-file [RET] .emacs`: loads the buffer (no need to restart emacs)
- `C-h a`: If you are interested in some specific action, you can look it up
- `C-h v [RET] variable`: can inspect the variable, check the value of `explicit-bash-args` for instance

And, btw, I'm not sure what the "--login -i" does, but someone stated in a comment that you should have that so "ls" would work. If you have your cygwin bin path in your PATH environment variable, bash will find ls anyway. No need to escape the path variable either, this is handled by bash (do an `echo $PATH` in bash when you get it working and you'll see).

Comment: There's also this if one wants to learn emacs key shortcuts: http://refcards.com/docs/gildeas/gnu-emacs/emacs-refcard-a4.pdf

Comment: This looks like a fantastic answer! I will try what you said tomorrow and accept your answer after that. Massive +1 for the helpful tips too.