# Emacs shell-specific environment variables

Tags: shell, emacs, windows-8, cygwin, environment-variables

In native emacs on windows, how can I specify environment variables for launching my shell inside emacs without modifying emacs' environment? In my specific case I'd like to set `HOME` to a cygwin-specific value for zsh without modifying where emacs thinks it's config file lives.

I've tried some things like changing my shell to `env -u HOME ...\zsh.exe`, but that seems to break `(shell-command)` (it appeared to involve argument order).

If this command existed, it would probably do what I want:

```
(setq explicit-zsh-environment '("HOME" nil))
```

I've read a bunch of related questions like ([How can I run Cygwin Bash Shell from within Emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/235254/1563816)), but the unusual part for me is that all my config files are cygwin-`ln`-ed or windows-`mklink`-ed into a git repo and cygwin and windows take very different and incompatible approaches to symlinks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this about running `zsh` as a shell inside Emacs (i.e. *not* about starting Emacs from a zsh shell), and having the environment that the inferior zsh process sees be different to the environment that Emacs has?

If so, you can bind the <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> `process-environment` variable when you start a process. e.g.:

```el
(let ((process-environment '("HOME=/tmp")))
  (call-interactively 'shell))
```

```
$ echo $HOME
/tmp
```

Comment: This is good, but is there a way to automatically apply it to `shell-command` and M-x `shell`?

Comment: Is it just shell processes you're concerned with? If you want it to affect *every* process you call from Emacs, then you could just modify the variable directly, rather than let-binding it. Then you wouldn't need to do anything else.

Comment: I think I'm getting myself into a weird place here. I just need to accept that until I find something better than having a cygwin-specific home directory I'm going to have to deal with a few inconsistencies. I'm going to try just modifying the variable and see what kind of issues I run into.

Comment: Well the first broken thing I've encountered is that all the bookmark functions try to open .emacs.d in the new HOME directory. Going to have to revert to writing a cygwin-shell function unless there is a way to affect only the "shell" functions.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Emacs manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Interactive-Shell.html):

> Emacs sends the new shell the contents of the file `~/.emacs_shellname` as input, if it exists, where *shellname* is the name of the file that the shell was loaded from. For example, if you use `bash`, the file sent to it is `~/.emacs_bash`. If this file is not found, Emacs tries with `~/.emacs.d/init_shellname.sh`.

So for `zsh` you would put inside `~/.emacs.d/init_zsh.sh` something like:

```
export HOME=/tmp
```